# How to update database entries instead of creating new entries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudant, fitbit

I'm currently working on a web app where we use wearables to monitor some vital parameters. For integration test purposes i'm using a fitbit.
The app is written in angular/javascript, the database is from cloudant.
My question is: How do you keep the database entries updated in general? I want to request the data from the wearable every two hours and update the already existing entry for that day instead of creating a new one to prevent duplicates.

So far i have thought of two things:

1. store today's data in a variable, especially the ID of the database entry to update every few hours and clear the variable at 0:00.
2. before every update get all entries and check if there is an entry for today's date. If so get the ID of said entry and update it, otherwise create a new one

I'm not really satisfied with either of the solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is nothing like 'replace into' for that kind of DB, maybe option 1 or something like redis and a cron who does your option 2 once a day.

Comment: I prefer 1st solution but a bit different way. For each entry you must have to receive a callback and store the last time you insert. While inserting new data you should check the date with variable date. With respect to this comparison you may decide what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating existing documents in Cloudant/CouchDB can be done, but you open yourself up to conflicts. Creating a new document for each sample is actually a good approach for many "IoT" type scenarios using Cloudant. You can then use a view to materialise the data. Your documents could look like this:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2016-12-01T13:25:02.000Z",
   "type": "pressure",
   "value": 110.0
}
```

Then use a design document that emits the data, along the lines of

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.timestamp && doc.value && doc.type) {
        var ts = Date.parse(doc.timestamp);
        emit([doc.type, ts], doc.value);
    }
}
```

More info here: https://cloudant.com/blog/introduction-to-document-conflicts-part-three/

Comment: Your example works fine for data like blood pressure or oxygen saturation where you have a 'static' value at a set time. The problem I encounter is with 'incrementing' data. e.g. steps per day or calories burned per day. Let's say I request the wearable data twice a day then I'll get one DB entry with 3000 steps and another with 6000 steps.

Comment: You have them in time order in the view - just pick the last one if you are only interested in the total. Each entry will represent the total at the time the sample was captured.

Comment: I agree with @xpqz. Data storage is cheap. Keeping the incremental data also gives you the ability to make graphs over time.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you for your help.